# Im getting nothing from the terminal when Im expecting even numbers on RUBY script

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a script in ruby where given an array I have to identify an even number. I know there is an integrated method to achieve that. But for the sake of this assignment I should find another way.
So far I have this code, which return nothing to the terminal (it doesn't return errors or nothing similar to have a clue):

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

num_even = Proc.new {
  if i % 2 == 0
    puts "#{numberEven=[i]}"
    break
  end
}

def my_find(numbers)
  numbers.each do |i|
    yield
  end
end

my_find(numbers){num_even}
```

I have also tried to do this modification :

```
my_find(numbers){&num_even}
```

I know this is a problem about blocks and procs. And I have not still caught it.

Comment: A minor point: `i.even?` is a bit cleaner and reads better than `i % 2 == 0`.

Comment: You have passed to my_find a block (effectively a Proc object), and the body of the block again returns a Proc object. `num_even` is passed around, but it is never actually called. In addition, you pass to your `numbers.each....` block a number, name it `i`, put this value is nowhere used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass argument to the proc

```rb
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

num_even =
  Proc.new do |i|
    if i % 2 == 0
      puts i
    end
  end

def my_find(numbers)
  numbers.each do |i|
    yield(i)
  end
end

my_find(numbers, &num_even)
# will print
# 2
# 4
# 6
```

Comment: Suggestion: `puts i if i.even?`